# Need Google Play Services Changelog / Release notes

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am trying to find change-logs for `Google Play Services` for Android.When I am trying to use latest `Google Play Service SDK` with my Library project My app crashes since It was complied with earlier version of Google Play Service SDK.New SDK doesn't contains certain methods which were available in previous versions.

I would really appreciate If somebody can point me out to Google Play services changelog.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Vipul, were you ever able to find a good, technical release notes page?  I've only found very marketing heavy / "hey look at our new awesome features" pages after searching & following the links in the answers.

Answer (score 6):

There you go,

GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES RELEASE NOTES:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Google's blog post explaining the changes in Google Play Services 4.1 (aka Rev. 14), released in early January 2014:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/01/google-play-services-41.html

Answer (score -9):

Try this,

- Go to your project
- Right click and select Android Tools
- Select option Add Supportive Library
- Done.